# How do I create a role in Discord?

Tags: discord

How do I create a role in Discord? Somewhere in the configuration there is this possibility, but it seems fairly hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Choose the server in the left panel
2. Choose the upper dropdown menu in the second-most left column
3. Choose "Server Settings"
4. Choose "Roles", - the second row in the left panel
5. Create the role there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will have to go to Server Settings, This can be accessed by going to your server first. You then need to go to the Roles Menu (Where you view your roles). Lastly you go up to the top right and click New Role or there could be a '+' instead.